# Missing System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: portable-class-library, hmacsha1

I want to use the `HMACSHA1` class in a project but the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography` is missing. If I add the reference `System.Security`, I find the namespace `Cryptography` but without the class `HMACSHA1`. And I can't find the namespace `Windows.Security.Cryptography` which seems to replace `System.Security.Cryptography`.

My projet targets the framework `.NET 4.5`and the `.NET` for Windows Store apps and He use `Nuget` on `Visual 2012` on `Windows 7`.

Someone have a solution to this problem ?

Comment: can you dump more information on your referenced assembly? which path are you using? which version are you using? btw according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1` resides in `mscorlib.dll`

Comment: I have the `.Net Portable Subset` in the References (.../Framework/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile7).

Comment: please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx to see whether your needed subset is covered for your scenario and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx: .NET Framework (Supported in: 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0), 
.NET Framework Client Profile (Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1), 
.NET for Windows Phone apps (Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1)

Comment: My project targets `.NET 4.5`and `Windows 8` like the `HMACSHA1`. I don't understand why the namespace `Cryptography` is missing.

Comment: The `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace is not part of *Windows 8/Store apps*; as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454038.aspx) it is missing from the `System.Security` namespaces in the *.NET API for Windows Store apps*. Therefore it is evidently not available in a PCL profile targeting *Windows 8* either. You will need to create separate projects for .NET and *Windows 8*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MSDN entry on [`HMACSHA1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx]

There's no information that it is included in the `Portable Class Library`.

BUT: there's [Portable Class Libraries Contrib](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/) out there, which includes a port of `HMACSHA1`

Comment: Also check out PCL Crypto: https://pclcrypto.codeplex.com/  It has a NuGet package so it's probably easier to consume.

Comment: It's still in beta, so I preferred create a new project to wrap the class to add the hmac.

Answer (score 1):

I had what sounds like a similar problem in a newly created C# console application. By default System reference showed some of System.Security, but not any of the Cryptography stuff. I had to right click 'References', 'Add Reference' and select 'System Security' after which I had access to the Cryptography stuff.

I'm fairly new to C# so sorry if my description isn't up to snuff or if this solution doesn't apply to mobile apps. Maybe helps someone else. thx